# Fix Characters Wordpress Ionic App

Tags: rest-api, json

Special Characters in my ionic App are displayed weird. For example when I have a quote in my title (headline) it's displayed as follows: `&#220;` for opening" and `&#221;` for a closing"

I have changed already in my wordpress the following

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

to:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Purged all Cache but the problem is the same.

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after doing excessive research I came to the conclusion that I have to add `[innerHTML]` into the span/title/h1